# Apache Error: File does not exist /var/www/html/appserv

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I'm on a newly purchased VPS with CentOS 5. When I try to start Apache, it logs the following error:

```
file does not exist /var/www/html/appserv
```

Appserv, I can see when googling it, is a PHP/mysql stack install. I did not install it and yum says there is no such package installed. Why then, is Apache looking for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file and search for appserv

Comment: it turns out the new install had not loaded the proper conf and after a httpd reload the error was gone. there are other problems now but just in case anyone ever googles the same problem, they will get a little answer here.